# Symfony : Get entity in radio_widget

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

With Symfony, I have a radio form from entity :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('color', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Color::class,
            'expanded' => true,
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => 'radio-inline'
            ],
            'label' => 'label.color',
            ....
```

But when I dump() in `radio_widget`, I don't have entity :

```
array:28 [▼
  "value" => "1"
  "attr" => []
  "form" => FormView {#975 ▶}
  "id" => "news_category_versions_0_color_1"
  "name" => "1"
  "full_name" => "news_category[versions][0][color]"
  "disabled" => false
  "label" => "Blue"
  "label_format" => null
  "multipart" => false
  "block_prefixes" => array:4 [▶]
  "unique_block_prefix" => "_news_category_versions_entry_color_entry"
  "translation_domain" => false
  "cache_key" => "_news_category_versions_entry_color_entry_radio"
  "errors" => FormErrorIterator {#1186 ▶}
  "valid" => true
  "data" => false
  "required" => true
  "size" => null
  "label_attr" => []
  "compound" => false
  "method" => "POST"
  "action" => ""
  "submitted" => false
  "help_translation_domain" => null
  "checked" => false
  "parent_label_class" => "radio-inline"
  "app" => AppVariable {#1216 ▶}
]
```

Can I get entity in `radio_widget` for customize it ? Each radio have a specific color in entity (blue, red, green, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

App\Entity\Color:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Color
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ColorRepository")
 */
class Color
{
    /**
     * @var int $id
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ColorProduct", mappedBy="color", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->product = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Color
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\ColorProduct $product
     *
     * @return Color
     */
    public function addProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\ColorProduct $product)
    {
        $this->product[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\ColorProduct $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\ColorProduct $product)
    {
        $this->product->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

A relation with the color entity in ColorProductEntity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ColorRepository")
 *
 */
class ColorProduct
{
    /**
     * @var int $id
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Color", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $color;




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set color
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Color $color
     *
     * @return ColorProduct
     */
    public function setColor(\AppBundle\Entity\Color $color = null)
    {
        $this->color = $color;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get color
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Color
     */
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
}
```

The formType for colorProduct:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;


use AppBundle\Entity\Color;
use AppBundle\Entity\ColorProduct;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ColorProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder->add('color', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => Color::class,
            'choice_label'  => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c');
            },
            'expanded' => true,
            'required' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => ColorProduct::class
            )
        );
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/product/color", name="product_color")
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function addColorProduct(Request $request) {
        $colorType = new ColorProduct();
        $form = $this->createForm(ColorProductType::class, $colorType);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
           //.........
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:product:color.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

Twig template:

```
<h1>Color product</h1>

{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.color) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The result:

[image]